# PyQt update QLabel

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a QLabel that I dynamically update with a new .text like this

```
self.ui.mylabel.text = 'foobar'
```

The problem is that after that it doesn't update the new value on the window.

I tried calling `self.app.processEvents()` or even an update on the label itself `self.ui.mylabel.update()` and `self.ui.mylabel.repaint()` to no avail.

How do I get the QLabel widget to reflect the change?

Answer (score 8):

I was doing it wrong. Calling `self.ui.mylabel.setText('foobar')` rather than accessing the property directly did the job.